# How to combine 2 FFMPEG Filter commands in one line?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to mirror a video and then watermark it with FFMPEG and I want to do all of this in one process. The Watermark part I've already figured out, but I do not know how I can mirror the video first without corrupting the whole line while doing so.

```
-y -i "{INPUT_FILE}" -i "C:\Users\Username\watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" -codec:a copy "{OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

This is what I use to watermark the file. I know that you can separate the filters and use "," in order to fit in the "vf -hflip" in there, but whenever I try to include it like this

```
-y -i "{INPUT_FILE}" -i "C:\Users\Username\watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5", -vf hflip -codec:a copy "{OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

I get errors I do not understand.

Perhaps anyone can help me and try to figure out how I can mirror the video and watermark it after flipping within one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
-y -i "{INPUT_FILE}" -i "C:\Users\Username\watermark.png" -filter_complex "[0]hflip[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" -codec:a copy "{OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

- `[0]hflip[bg];` - `[0]` refers to `{INPUT_FILE}`. Give it to the hflip filter. Label the output from hflip `[bg]` or whatever you prefer. This is a standalone filterchain so end it with `;`.
- `[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5` - Use `[bg]` as the background, and `[1]` (refers to `watermark.png`) as foreground and overlay them.

For more info see [FFmpeg Filtering Intro](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction).